# How to replace formulas with values when enabling the checkbox through scripts. (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am an absolute zero in programming Scripts for Google tabs. Sorry if I ask a strange question, or fill it out incorrectly. I am really newbie on this site.

There is an example of a sheets:
Columns A and B are just numbers
Column C and D contain formulas. Like C2=(A2+B2), D2=(A2-B2)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNvFU.png)
[image]

A task:
I want that when I click on the button or the checkbox next to the line. All values on this line were inserted as values. (I mean, formulas were deleted and replaced with values) and the checkbox was deleted.

I tried to do it through recording a macro and got the code, but I still couldn't figure it out:

1. how to activate the script for the checkbox.
2. how to make each line have its own checkbox and it works.

```
function _111() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('TRUE');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:D2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:D2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

Please help me if you can.

UPD Special for MetaMan:
[My TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6UrX.png)
Name of sheet is "Sell tab"
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');//debug
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  //sh.getRange('P1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));//debug
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart==5 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('sheet');//debug
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,3,1,2).setValues(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,3,1,2).getValues());
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).clearDataValidations().clearContent();
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

[onedit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

[clearDataValidations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearDataValidations())

[setValues(),getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

It might be helpful for you to remove the comments from my debug lines.  If you do not have anything special in P1 that's where I have the event object for the onEdit trigger being displayed.  I like to look at it while I debug the problem.

Comment: Hello, i understand that i'm absolutely stupid user. and cant understand your script to my main tab. Maybe can i connected with you by any way? Email or facebook or else. for short conversation. or ask to help? or maybe can i ask you help me directly in my own tabs. not like example tab?

Comment: May be you should try to read the code and search the methods I used in the documentation and try to figure it out on your own before we chat.

Comment: yeap, but the problem is that all doc on the Eng language. and i'm not programmer. anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: if this task is not hard for you, Could you be able to make a script directly in my tab? with mine values?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow links to offsite resources.  It is any easy script to write.  I'm sorry about the language issue that would be a huge hurdle for me as well.  But the reality is that I'm a much better student than I am a teacher.

Comment: sorry for my persistence, but if I throw you a specific example of my table. could you tell me how to arrange it correctly? Without switching to third-party resources.

Comment: I created an update in my question with a link to the picture and the title of the sheet.

Comment: To be totally honest with you, that's a slippery slope that I don't want to venture onto.  At some point your going to have to decide whether you want to learn how to do this stuff or not.  If you don't want to learn how to do it that's okay.  You can go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/topusers) and pick one of the other volunteers and go to their profile and see if they wish to help you.  Or just hang around this question and see if someone else wants to take on a new student.

Comment: thanks for your easy push.  I was really able to figure it out a little and customize your solution for myself.  I was even able to understand that I did not really need a replacement for formulas, but simply remove the validation check on the columns I needed.  I managed to remake it as I need.  but 1 problem remained, I don't know why, but the script only works for 1 line, can you point me to the error?  how to make it work on each line separately?

Comment: It only works for the range `sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,3,1,2)`  the e.range.rowStart comes from the event object.  The 3 is column 3 or column C , the 1 is the number of rows, and 2 is the number of columns.